# Yii2 REST api bearer authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, reactjs, yii2-advanced-app, bearer-token

I am using **Yii2** framework as the backend and **react** js for the client side. I am trying to create REST api with **HTTPBearer** authentication but always get a **401 Unauthorized error**. I have followed the Yii2 Rest api authentication with no success. I have also implemented **findIdentityByAccessToken** on user.php and **access_token** on my sql. My files:-

Folder structure:-

-api
    --config
         --main.php
         --main-local.php
          ...
    --modules
         --v1
       --controllers
         --CheckinsController.php

-backend
-common
-frontend
..

main.php

```
 <?php
 
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);
 
return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'   // here is our v1 modules
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'enableSession' => false,
            'loginUrl' =>'',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\Request',
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ]
                ],
                  [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/event', 
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET test' => 'test'
                    ],     
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/checkins', 
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                     'GET checkinview/<id:\d+>' => 'checkinview/'
                    ],     
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

CheckinsController.php

```
<?php 

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use api\modules\v1\models\CheckinApi;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\web\Response;

class CheckinsController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Events';

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()   
    ];
     $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ];

    return $behaviors;
}

  
public function actionCheckinview($id)
{
//     \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $query = new CheckinApi();
    $test = 
        [
            'count' => $query->Checkincount($id),
            'checkinid' => $id,
            'useridused' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id,

        ];
         return $test;//Testing purpose
}
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
    ];
}

public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();

    // remove fields that contain sensitive information
    unset($fields['auth_key'], $fields['password_hash'], $fields['password_reset_token'],$fields['access_token']);

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
     return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}

/**
 * Finds user by username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}

/**
 * Finds user by password reset token
 *
 * @param string $token password reset token
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
{
    if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
        return null;
    }

    return static::findOne([
        'password_reset_token' => $token,
        'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Finds out if password reset token is valid
 *
 * @param string $token password reset token
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
{
    if (empty($token)) {
        return false;
    }
    $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
    $parts = explode('_', $token);
    $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
    return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryKey();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param string $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}

/**
 * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
 *
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

/**
 * Generates "remember me" authentication key
 */
public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

 /**
 * Generates "api" access token
 */
public function generateAccessToken()
{
    $this->access_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString($length = 16);
}

/**
 * Generates new password reset token
 */
public function generatePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security-       >generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
}

/**
 * Removes password reset token
 */
public function removePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = null;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!! trying to get around this problem for days, but no success. Dont know if it is a simple error done by me!!

Comment: You can use all or use one at a time

Answer (score 1):

- Give me "user.php" for checking more...
- The "CheckinsController" should like below LOCs (don't add more information when you don't control it).

```
    namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

    use yii\rest\ActiveController;
    use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
    use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
    use api\modules\v1\models\CheckinApi;
    use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
    use yii\web\Response;

    class CheckinsController extends ActiveController
    {
        public $modelClass = 'common\models\Events';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()   
        ]; 
        return $behaviors;
    } 
    }
```

- You can refer a manual here: http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/
- Also can refer this project https://github.com/NguyenDuyPhong/yii2_advanced_api_phong (including database) - It's working very well on my localhost. 
  Hopefully I helped you something!

Comment: Thanks for your time and response, would give it a shot. And i have also included user.php. Do check it out.I am using generateAccessToken method for api

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case you did. I am using `ReactJS` for client dan Yii2 for api.

In your case, check this rule:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/checkins', 
    'extraPatterns' => [
     'GET checkinview/<id:\d+>' => 'checkinview/'
    ],     
]
```

This code should be:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/checkins', 
    'tokens' => ['{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'], --> because you stil use ActiveController
    'pluralize' => false, --> for disable pluralize
    'extraPatterns' => [
     'GET checkinview/<id:\d+>' => 'checkinview' --> remove '/' sign
     'OPTIONS checkinview/<id:\d+>' => 'options', --> for corsFilter
    ],     
]
```

Comment: `'OPTIONS checkinview/<id:\d+>' => 'options', --> for corsFilter` if I am missing this will it show status code as 401 ? Unauthenticated whereas the same request works fine in PostMan

Comment: its for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), if you using axios or fetch js for HTTP promise, `OPTIONS` request is used to check if you are allowed to perform the `GET, POST, DELETE, UPDATE`.

jQuery use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while axios or fetch use `application/json`. 

please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['token'],
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, when checking on firebug, there are two calls made, one GET and one OPTIONS. The GET will return 200 OK and WITHOUT response, while the OPTIONS will return 401 Unauthorized access.

When browsing in google, found out that this simple line will make it work.

```
public function behaviors() {
    return
            \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                'corsFilter' => [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                ],
                'authenticator' => [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                    'except' => ['options'],
                ],
    ]);
}
```

But, I do not understand why OPTIONS, why the GET return no response? Can anyone elaborate more on this?