# Yii2 Rest API user authentication

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am implementing Rest API in yii2. I want to authenticate the user using access token. I have referred various SO answers as follows

- [Rest api bearer authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720399/yii2-rest-api-bearer-authentication)
- [Rest api bearer auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662459/yii2-rest-api-bearer-authentication)
- [Yii2 Rest api authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453378/yii2-rest-api-authentication)

But I m not clear, which authentication method I should use and how I will get user identity.

I have created `findIdentityByAccessToken()` method in my user identity class as suggested in [Yii2 Rest guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html) .

Below is the `behaviour` implemented in my controller

```
public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'except' => ['login','forgot-password']
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

now, how I will get the user identity inside my controller action? As far as i know, access token will be set from the web service inside request header.

Note : I am using Yii2 advanced app
please help me.

Comment: What exacly doesn't work? if you wan't to use access tokens implement the HttpBearerAuth behavior. if implemented correctly you can access the authenticated user with Yii::$app->user

Comment: I m confused about which auth behaviour I should use for access token validation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer there's more than one possibility to implement this behavior.

Both `HttpBearerAuth` and `HttpBasicAuth` can use the `findIdentityByAccessToken()` methode when configured correctly. the behavior you should use depends on the way you want users to authenticate themselves.

if you read the documentation of `HttpBasisAuth` [HttpBasicAuth](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbasicauth.html) you'll see

> The default implementation of HttpBasicAuth uses the loginByAccessToken() method of the user application component and only passes the user name. This implementation is used for authenticating API clients.

`loginByAccesToken` will invoke the `findIdentityByAccesToken` methode
You can manipulate this behavior by defining a closure in the auth attribute see [auth attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbasicauth.html#$auth-detail).

`HttpBeareAuth` almost does the same. it also implements the `loginByAccessToken`

So what make the two different from each other? simple the location where the get the data from. where `HttpBasicAuth` expects that client has set the basic header example `header('Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password"));` (PHP has build in support for this see: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

the `HttpBearerAuth` expects that the header is defined as the following `header('Authorization: Bearer '. $token);`

So the solution you should use depends on the way you want users/clients to authenticate themselves. you could also use the `QueryParamAuth` which gives the users the possibility to authenticate themselves whit a GET param see [queryparamauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-queryparamauth.html)

And if you want to use a custom header let's say X-API-Token create your own custom class that implements the `AuthMethod` interface see [AuthMethod](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-authmethod.html)

Hope this helps